# WSO2IS: Verifing user is already logged using ssoTokenId and IdentitySAMLSSOServiceSoap webservice

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have followed the steps [in this tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server) to retrieve a `ssoTokenID` in my HTTP response header from the WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0. I am running this locally.

I also have the the `IdentitySAMLSSOService` available at:

```
https://localhost:9443/services/IdentitySAMLSSOService?wsdl
```

This service provides 3 operations:

- authenticate
- doSingleLogout
- validateRequest

Using the authenticate operation, I want to verify that the user is indeed logged in. I expect to use the ssoTokenId that I have retrieved earlier. Also, I assume that the JSESSIONID is not relevant at this point.

```
ssoTokenId=1E5F811E2FAC8AFBEE31621E889DE3FD
```

I have used soapUI to start a SOAP request to the authenticate service. I have added basic authentication username/password.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:authenticate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:authReqDTO>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:assertionConsumerURL>http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/consumer</xsd1:assertionConsumerURL>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:assertionString></xsd1:assertionString>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:certAlias></xsd1:certAlias>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:claim></xsd1:claim>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:doSignAssertions>false</xsd1:doSignAssertions>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:doSingleLogout>false</xsd1:doSingleLogout>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:id></xsd1:id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:issuer>saml2.demo</xsd1:issuer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:loginPageURL></xsd1:loginPageURL>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:logoutURL></xsd1:logoutURL>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:nameIDFormat></xsd1:nameIDFormat>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:password></xsd1:password>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <xsd1:requestedClaims></xsd1:requestedClaims>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:rpSessionId>1E5F811E2FAC8AFBEE31621E889DE3FD</xsd1:rpSessionId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:stratosDeployment>false</xsd1:stratosDeployment>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:subject></xsd1:subject>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:useFullyQualifiedUsernameAsSubject>false</xsd1:useFullyQualifiedUsernameAsSubject>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:username></xsd1:username>
         </xsd:authReqDTO>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:sessionId></xsd:sessionId>
      </xsd:authenticate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I received the following response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:authenticateResponse xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2301:SAMLSSORespDTO" xmlns:ax2299="http://base.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax2301="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
            <ax2301:assertionConsumerURL xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2301:errorMsg>login.fail.message</ax2301:errorMsg>
            <ax2301:loginPageURL xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2301:respString><![CDATA[&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;saml2p:Response ID=&quot;dgjkpdhojndphkhklhlpcdjnbakojekiajbflpjp&quot; IssueInstant=&quot;2013-07-11T08:46:32.008Z&quot; Version=&quot;2.0&quot; xmlns:saml2p=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol&quot;&gt;&lt;saml2:Issuer Format=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity&quot; xmlns:saml2=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion&quot;&gt;https://localhost:9443/samlsso&lt;/saml2:Issuer&gt;&lt;saml2p:Status&gt;&lt;saml2p:StatusCode Value=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed&quot;/&gt;&lt;saml2p:StatusMessage&gt;login.fail.message&lt;/saml2p:StatusMessage&gt;&lt;/saml2p:Status&gt;&lt;/saml2p:Response&gt;]]></ax2301:respString>
            <ax2301:sessionEstablished>false</ax2301:sessionEstablished>
            <ax2301:subject xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:authenticateResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried to add the value of `ssoTokenId` in different places:

- I have tried adding the value of `ssoTokenID` to `<xsd1:rpSessionId>`
- I have also tried to add it to `<xsd:sessionId>`
- Also tried adding it to the header of the SOAP request.

Unfortunately, in all cases, there is a `login.fail.message`. What is the proper way to check if a user is already authenticated?

Comment: Are there existing stubs for this web service?

Comment: Any luck buddy ? @JimRoy